# App crashes when I use check box widget

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I'm trying to implement a toggle button an a check box in my android app like this:

In XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"     
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" 
tools:context=".Main">

<ToggleButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:textOn="Dark Background"
    android:textOff="Light Background"

    android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="I want pizza with"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toggleButton"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/toggleButton"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/toggleButton"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Cheese"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/toggleButton"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/toggleButton"
    android:checked="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In Java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
    ToggleButton tb = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);


    tb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            } else {
                rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
        }
    });

    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
    final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    cb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            boolean checked = ((CheckBox) v).isChecked();
            if (checked) {
                tv.setText("You want pizza with cheese");
            } else {
                tv.setText("Oh! I see. you don't like cheese.");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is, every time I test the app it crashes and I can't find why.

So if anyone has any idea why, please help.

Comment: Please provide a stack trace.

Comment: You should post the stack trace....but You wrote : boolean checked = ((CheckBox) v).isChecked(); ... why You are using (CheckBox)v) ? You allready have initialized CheckBox before, so You just need to boolean checked = cb.isChecked(); and make cb as final.

Answer (score 0):

thry to use this listener:

```
cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {

   }
   }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the following line defining your `CheckBox` in your activity

```
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
```

But in your layout you define its id to be `checkBox`

Changing your code to the following should fix this

```
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
```

You should also use a `CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()` to determine when your `CheckBox` state is changed:

```
cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

       @Override
       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
           if (isChecked) {
               tv.setText("You want pizza with cheese");
           } else {
               tv.setText("Oh! I see. you don't like cheese.");
           }
       }
   }
);
```

Comment: if it is from wrong spelling, tha app won´t usually compile, I don´t think that this is the issue here..another possible issue could be, that in another layout the id is "checkbox"...

Comment: Thank you Ed. It was the id i didn't notice.